# Div Hover only works when hovering text

Tags: html, css

I'm making a navbar and for each button, I have a <div> and a , the div is the box and the a is the text+hyperlink.

I want to have my div change colors when I hover it, the problem is if I add a div :hover to my CSS it only changes colors when I hover over the , and not the div. So the box only changes colors when I hover the text.

I'm also having to copy everything from my normal div to the hover div because if I only change the color only the text will. (the last image is what it looks like when my div hover has only a background-color property)
The red circles on the images are where my mouse is.

I hope it didn't sound too confusing.
Code and example below:

```
(this is inside a <nav>)

<div class="menu">
            <div class="mapbox"><a class="map" href="">Erangel</a><br></div>
            <div class="mapbox"><a class="map" href="">Miramar</a><br></div>
            <div class="mapbox"><a class="map" href="">Sanhok</a><br></div>
            <div class="mapbox"><a class="map" href="">Vikendi</a><br></div>
            <div class="mapbox"><a class="map" href="">Taego</a><br></div>
            <div class="mapbox"><a class="map" href="">Karakin</a></div>
</div>
```

```
.map{
    font-family: 'Rubik Mono One', Arial;
    font-size: 1vw;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0.125vw 0.125vw #282b30;
}
.mapbox{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #424549;
    border-radius: 1vw;
    width: 12.5vw;
    height: 2vw;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0.85vw;
    box-shadow: 0.225vw 0.225vw #1e2124;
}
.mapbox :hover{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #7289da;
    border-radius: 1vw;
    width: 12.5vw;
    height: 2vw;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0.85vw;
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: can anyone please close this, its answered but i cant close it, thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swapping the `<div>` and the `<a>` fixed it.

Instead of the `<a>` being inside the `<div>`, put the `<div>` inside the `<a>` and change the CSS hover class to the  class.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is you should not leave space before `:hover`.

Before:
`.mapbox :hover`

After: `.mapbox:hover`

```css
.map {
  font-family: 'Rubik Mono One', Arial;
  font-size: 1vw;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0.125vw 0.125vw #282b30;
}

.mapbox {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #424549;
  border-radius: 1vw;
  width: 12.5vw;
  height: 2vw;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0.85vw;
  box-shadow: 0.225vw 0.225vw #1e2124;
}

.mapbox:hover {
  background-color: #7289da;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="mapbox"><a class="map" href="#">Erangel</a><br></div>
  <div class="mapbox"><a class="map" href="#">Miramar</a><br></div>
  <div class="mapbox"><a class="map" href="#">Sanhok</a><br></div>
  <div class="mapbox"><a class="map" href="#">Vikendi</a><br></div>
  <div class="mapbox"><a class="map" href="#">Taego</a><br></div>
  <div class="mapbox"><a class="map" href="#">Karakin</a></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You may want to note that the original selector, selects a hovered child of `.mapbox`